# How do I use Chrome Developer debugging shortcuts on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extensions

I am debugging javascript on a web page using Chrome Web Developer Tools. On Windows, I can use <kbd>F11</kbd> to step into a function while using the debugger.

However, when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> on my Mac, The volume just increases. <kbd>F11</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> doesn't do it either. How can I use Chrome Web Developer keyboard shortcuts on a Mac?

Comment: Other alternative to **Step into** on Mac is `Command`+`;` (semi-colon) and to **Step out** is  `Shift`+`Command`+`;`  (semi-colon)

Comment: I like my mac, but i hate their shortcuts. all of them are terrible

Comment: Haha I have the same problem, but my volume decreases, not increases.

Comment: I've had the same issue today. When pressing F10 the window would shrink...Tomorrow I'll try something...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- `Continue`: <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> (forward slash) on Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> (forward slash) on other platforms.
- `Step over`: <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) on Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) on other platforms.
- `Step into`: <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon) on Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon); on other platforms.
- `Step out`: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon) on Mac or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon) on other platforms.
- `Next call frame`: <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (period) on all platforms.
- `Previous call frame`: <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) on all platforms.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts)

Comment: in OSX fn-F11 shows the desktop or something like that -- all the windows fly away to the sides of the screen

Comment: On macOS Catalina to `Continue` : Command+\ (backslash) worked for me

Comment: For me macOS Catalina, only: `fn + Command +\ (backslash)`, worked

Answer (score 45):

It works:

1. Go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Keyboard`.  Make sure you have **Enabled** `Use F1/F2 as standard function keys`.
2. Go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`. Choose `Mission Control` on the left panel, then look to the right panel and **disable** F11 to `Show Desktop`.

Comment: Coming from Windows to OS X, this is one of the biggest annoyances I have struggled with the past two weeks... Now I can debug properly lol. FANKOOOOOO!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: #2 is important

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) as well. The keymap for a full-sized keyboard looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>CHROME</appname>
    <equal>com.google.Chrome</equal>
  </appdef>

  <item>
    <name>CHROMEDEBUGGINGKEY</name>
    <appendix>This maps the F13, F14 and F15 keys to Chrome debugging keys</appendix>
    <identifier>private.swap_chrome_to_debug_settings</identifier>
    <only>CHROME</only>
    <!--<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, KeyCode::TAB</autogen>-->
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F13, KeyCode::F8
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F14, KeyCode::F10
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F15, KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::F16, KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: This used to work very well for me. However, recently, the 2nd & 3rd keymap above is not working. I am using Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) and Karabiner 10.22.0. I have mapped "Step Over" to F6 and "Step into" to F5. I am using mac over screen sharing from another mac.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is using Karabiner Elements, it might be the one blocking Chrome functional hot keys. Opening Karabiner Elements preferences on the "Function Keys" tab and checking "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" did the trick for me.

[image]