# How do I use visual studio debugging shortcuts on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

I want to use 'Step into' debugging in visual studio. I saw question this, 'chrome developer debugging shortcuts on a mac'. I did 'Step over' method but I still can't do 'Step into' method.

> [How do I use Chrome Developer debugging shortcuts on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/451954/how-do-i-use-chrome-developer-debugging-shortcuts-on-a-mac)

This is the way in this answer, "how to 'Step into' debugging on Mac?"

- **F11**
- **Command-; (semi-colon)** on Mac
- **Control-; (semi-colon)** on other platforms.

When i do **F11**, query file open. When I do **Command-; (semi-colon)**, selected text delete. When I do **Control-; (semi-colon)**, nothing happened.

help me..

Comment: Why don't you just change the shortcut keys since your on a Mac?

Comment: @Ramhound      I didn't need to change shortcut keys before... Do i have to??

Comment: You made no mention using visual studio before Clarify your question

Comment: Do you think you're using Visual Studio on Mac OS X (which doesn't work), or are you just trying to use the same shortcut keys used in VS on another application (on a Mac)?  If the latter, which application?

Comment: @jimtut        ah!Latter. I'm using Visual Studio on Parallels application.

Comment: `F11` should be easy to remap, using the "Keyboard" preference pane.  You can remap keys per application (you'd choose Parallels, as that's the app that OSX knows about).  See if that works first, then maybe we can figure out the `Cmd/Ctrl-;` keys too.

Comment: I find this answer over at Apple StackExchange being the most effective solution:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311170/317586 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a Mac machine and the keyboard is a bit different than a PC machine. Visual Studio is a PC application that you run on a virtual machine in Parallel Desktops. Some shortcuts that you are so used to in Windows might not work as expected, and this you have already discovered. You can however customize keyboard shortcuts in Parallel Desktop, in order to achieve similar results.

To Customize Keyboard Shortcuts:

1. Do one of the following:

   - Option-click (Alt-click) the Parallels icon  in the menu bar and choose Preferences.
   - If the Parallels Desktop menu bar is visible at the top of the screen, choose Parallels Desktop > Preferences.
2. Click Keyboard.
3. If necessary, click the lock icon and enter an administrator password.

   - PD6_Configuring Keyboard Preferences
   - Pressing a key combination in the From column while working in a Windows program triggers the key combination in the To column.
4. Do one of the following:

   - To edit an existing key combination, double-click the key combination. Click modifier keys to select or deselect them. If you wish, change the character in the text field.
   - PD6_Remapping Keyboard
   - To delete a key combination, select it and click the Remove button CE_Button_Delete.
   - To add a new key combination, click the Add button PlusButton.
   - To disable a key combination without deleting it, click the checkbox next to the key combination to deselect it.
   - If you're using multiple operating systems with Parallels Desktop, you can create keyboard profiles for each OS.

   `Note: 1. Some key combinations can't be edited or deleted.`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using VMware, the same thing can be accomplished by:

1. From the Menu bar - VMware Fusion >> Preferences
2. Keyboard & Mouse
3. Select the Mac Host Shortcuts
4. Uncheck the Mac OS host Keyboard Shortcuts

This is better (in IMHO) because it does not send Mac shortcuts to the VM.  I have Windows 10 Pro / VS 2015 installed on my VM for when I work at home.  It keeps the keyboard command separate between the two.  I'm in PC mode - PC commands. I'm in Mac mode - Mac commands.

VMware help on the topic [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-6/topic/com.vmware.fusion.help.doc/GUID-A50D0E3C-9549-43B5-AB57-070F805780A3.html)